# UIView unable to get transparent property

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a subview to the window (for using it as side menu). It has a child view which is transparent view. However I am unable to get the transparent property when it runs in simulator.

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        frame  = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width:0, height:0)
        frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        sideMenuView.frame = frame
        sideMenuTransparentView.isOpaque = false
        sideMenuTransparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(sideMenuView)

    }
```

However I am seeing no effect of this to make the view as transparent. What's possibly wrong here and how should I proceed rectifying this?

The weird thing here is that when I replace the lines

```
sideMenuTransparentView.isOpaque = false
            sideMenuTransparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

with

```
sideMenuView.isOpaque = false
            sideMenuView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

I can see the effect. I am unable to understand what's going in here and how should I correct this.

Comment: You seem to have set the color as gray with 50% transparency. So it won't be fully transparent.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, can you explain with code?

Comment: If you want full transparency, you need to set the background color to UIColor.clear. Is this what you want?

Comment: To make a view transparent you can either use `.alpha` property of UIView that can be between 0-1, but all the subviews will be affected.
Or you can give background color with transparancy like: `UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)`.

Comment: @DojYiasLem check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to add the transparent view to the main `sideMenuView`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) // You need to call super when overriding

    frame  = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width:0, height:0)
    frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    sideMenuView.frame = frame
    sideMenuTransaparentView.frame = yourFrame // required frame
    sideMenuTransparentView.isOpaque = false
    sideMenuTransparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5) // 100% transparency
    sideMenuView.addSubview(view: sideMenuTransparentView)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(sideMenuView)

}
```

Also, you forgot to call `super`.